# Connect to Azure AD using username/password

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Api REST which can be reach by entering  a username/password .
how can i get access to this API from C#  ?

after a little search , i found somthing about using **AuthenticationContext** .. but it couldn't work for me   Authenticationcontext .AcquireToken(resource, clientId, credential);

where can i get the '**resource**' parameter  and the **ClientID** .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based most of my work on [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2016/01/18/azure-usage-of-cdn-api-to-load-and-purge-content/) that laid some groundwork.

You need to create a Native Application in your Azure AD first and add the *Windows Azure Service Management API* permission.

[image: Creating AD App]

The **ClientID** is obtained from this App.

This is the code I'm currently using to obtain a Token that can be used with the Management SDK:

```
string userName = "yourUserName";
string password = "yourPassword";
string directoryName = "yourDirectory.onmicrosoft.com";
string clientId = "{ClientId obtained by creating an App in the Active Directory}";
var credentials= new UserPasswordCredential(string.Format("{0}@{1}", userName, directoryName), password);
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + directoryName);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientID, credentials);
var jwtToken = result.AccessToken;
//Example accesing Azure Cdn Management API
string subscriptionId = "xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx";
using (var cdn = new CdnManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(jwtToken)) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId })
{
    //do something...
}
```

Your directory name can be obtained in the Azure Portal > Azure AD section, on **Domain names**.

[image: Domain name]

Comment: My app is hosted in an azure website : https://AppHostedName.azurewebsites.net/ 
for my example the directory name will be  'AppHopstedName' ?

Comment: You can see the Directory Name on Azure, go to the Azure AD service and check **Domain Names**. I edited the answer to include a screen capture.

Comment: Thanks Matias , you helped me a lot

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! :D Azure AD is not the most programmatic-friendly service.