# AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string, ClientCredential) is obsolete

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am using C# to connect to Azure Active Directory using
AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string, ClientCredential).

I am getting an error that this is obsolete. What is the alternative please?

Comment: can you include the error what you are getting?

Comment: 'AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string, ClientCredential)' is obsolete: 'As a security hygiene, this confidential flow API should not be used on this platform which only supports public client applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the **version of the SDK.** Some of the features are deprecated. Please check the below code block and also kindly check whether you're having a **native application** up and running to test.

```cs
 AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync (string resource, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential clientCredential);
```

Replace this code block with above mention code  block

```
AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(string, ClientCredential).
```

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-identitymodel-clients-activedirectory-authenticationcontext-acquiretokenasync%28system-string-microsoft-identitymodel-clients-activedirectory-clientcredential%29) and [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768576/connect-to-azure-ad-using-username-password) by Matias Quaranta which worked on the similar thread